# Removing Respond.js from ASP.NET MVC 5 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, respond.js

The abstract for [Respond.js](http://www.javascriptoo.com/respond-js) says

> [it] enable[s] responsive web designs in browsers that don't support CSS3 Media Queries - in particular, Internet Explorer 8 and under.

I am not planning on supporting said browsers for this application, so I'd prefer not to carry an unneeded dependency.  There are no package dependencies on it.  The only place it appears in code is in the supplied BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Can I simple remove this reference, and the package, without ill effect?

Comment: Yes, it's just a collection of polyfills.  Remove it and find out.

Comment: @Amy: Thanks.  Just didn't want to get into a situation further in where trying too re-add it would be a major PITA.